Auto Login with Python Selenium
Im trying to do an auto login with selenium, but it isn't "writing" my data neither clicking the login button:
      <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TNDZLZ2&gtm_auth=&gtm_preview=&gtm_cookies_win=x"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" id="tag-manager"></iframe>
<div class="popup-holder-bc full-screen  content-manager " style="">
<div class="popup-middleware-bc">
<div class="popup-inner-bc">
<i class="e-p-close-icon-bc bc-i-close-remove"></i>
<div class="entrance-popup-bc sign-in">
<div class="e-p-content-holder-bc">
<div class="e-p-content-bc"><div class="e-p-header-bc">
<a class="popup-t-logo-w-bc" href="/pb/">
<img class="hdr-logo-bc" src="/logo.png" alt=""></a>
<div class="e-p-sections-bc">
<div class="e-p-section-item-bc">
<button class="btn s-small register " type="button" title="Inscrever-se"><span>Inscrever-se</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="e-p-body-bc">
<form class="entrance-form-bc login popup" data-scroll-lock-scrollable=""><div class="form-sign-bc">
<div class="sg-n-text-row-1-bc">Já tem uma conta?</div>
<div class="sg-n-text-row-2-bc">Faça o login, estamos esperando por você!</div>
<div class="entrance-f-item-bc">
<div class="form-control-bc default ">
<label class="form-control-label-bc inputs">
**<input type="text" class="form-control-input-bc" name="username" step="0" value="">**
<i class="form-control-input-stroke-bc"></i>
<span class="form-control-title-bc ellipsis">Email / Usuário</span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="entrance-f-item-bc">
<div class="form-control-bc default has-icon ">
<label class="form-control-label-bc inputs">
**<input type="password" class="form-control-input-bc" autocomplete="current-password" name="password" step="0" value="">**
<i class="form-control-input-stroke-bc">
</i>
<span class="form-control-title-bc ellipsis">Senha</span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="entrance-f-item-bc entrance-f-item-checkbox-bc">
<div class="checkbox-control-bc">
<label class="checkbox-control-content-bc">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-control-input-bc" name="remember_me" step="0">
<i class="checkbox-control-icon-bc bc-i-checked">
</i>
<p class="checkbox-control-text-bc">Lembre-se de mim</p>
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="entrance-form-actions-holder-bc login-ext-1">
<div class="entrance-form-action-item-bc right">
**<button class="btn a-color " type="submit" title="Entrar">**<span>Entrar</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import telebot
import time
import Infos

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.playpix.com/pb/live-casino/home/-1/All?profile=open&account=profile&page=details')
time.sleep(5)

if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]') == 1:
    time.sleep(5)

    username=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input')
    password=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input')  

    username.send_keys(Infos.username) 
    password.send_keys(Infos.password)
    time.sleep(3)

    log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/button')
    log_in_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)

Im doing it with an "IF" cause the code is in loop and the website logoff me every hour, so i need it to check every loop to find when the login box exists and log in again.
Tried to write in different ways, but aways using the "same" method, i have other find elements in the code that works fine, the only problem is login

Can you share the URL if it's public? If not share the HTML of the page at least? Otherwise it's difficult for anyone to help you with a solution. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Sure: https://www.playpix.com/pb/live-casino/home/-1/All?profile=open&account=profile&page=details

Why do you need to stay logged in? I think the better way to do this is to create your script that accomplishes what you want and then schedule it to run every X mins or whatever. That way you aren't trying to keep it logged in, etc. which can be very tricky to do with timings, etc.

Also, we need the relevant HTML in your question, as text properly formatted. The URL would be helpful but it's blocked where I'm at.

I need to keep it logged because its a bet website and my script is analysing entries to go. I will edit the post with the HTML.

I've marked the parts i'm trying to get with "**"

Use relative XPaths instead of absolute XPaths which are more reliable. Refer this article to know more about these 2.

What is the difference between relative and absolute XPath in Selenium?

Coming to your code, I cannot entirely be sure what exactly is wrong as you have not shared the error/exception trace. Assuming the absolute XPath expressions are not able to locate the desired element, change the code to locate username, password and login button as below.
Change below code:
username=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/input')
password=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input')

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[6]/div/button')  

To:
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='username']")
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")

log_in_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Entrar']")

NOTE: From the HTML which you have shared, I can't see an IFRAME wrapping the desired elements(username, password and login button). However, if there is actually an IFRAME as parent node to these elements, then you need to switch into the iframe context first before performing any actions on these elements. Refer example code below:
# Below line will switch into the desired iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "<xpath of iframe>"))

# Perform all the required actions here, like sending text to username, password field and clicking on login button

# Use below code to come out of iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()

